# How to convert Time to an int in java

Tags: java, arrays, integer

So far i have this

```
 public int getDuration()
{
   int totalMinutes = 0;
   for (Flight f: flights) {
       Time st = flights.get(0).getDepartureTime();
       Time et = flights.get(flights.size()-1).getArrivalTime();
       int start = Integer.parseInt(st);
       int end = Integer.parseInt(st);
       totalMinutes = (start - end);
    }
   return totalMinutes;


}
```

I don't know how to return an integer value for st - et. Note that i'm using bluej thanks

Comment: It looks like you are already doing that, but you just have a typo: `int end = Integer.parseInt(st);` should be `int end = Integer.parseInt(et);`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store the time as an Integer. You will have to use a Long.

```
 long totalMiliSeconds = (st.getTime() - et.getTime());
```

Comment: One correction is that result of calculation is `totalMiliSeconds` in place of `totalMinutes `